# Batch-major vs time-major LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Do RNNs learn different dependency patterns when the input is batch-major as opposed to time-major?

Comment: I don't have a concrete answer, but it is context-dependent, with for example batches of matrices being multiplied together wanting batch-major storage (since each matmul is independent), and likewise for applying the same convolution to multiple images. Image processing is a major use of TensorFlow, so it's not too surprising that the convention seeps into places where it may not be optimal.

Comment: What about in the context of a static LSTM. I thought perhaps there were some emergent properties in the alignment of time steps within a batch, but I suppose these would also be discovered in time-major form.

Comment: I think LSTMs are going to always want time-major, since they'll be slicing based on time for their inputs. Other kinds of RNNs could be exceptions, maybe something like WaveNet would want batch-major.

Answer (score 5):

(Edit: sorry my initial argument was why it *makes sense* but I realized that it *doesn't* so this is a little OT.)

I haven't found the TF-groups reasoning behind this but it <s>does</s> **does not** make computational sense as ops are written in C++.

Intuitively, we want to mash up (multiply/add etc) different features from the same sequence on the same timestep. Different timesteps can’t be done in parallell while batch/sequences can so feature>batch/sequence>timestep.

By [default Numpy and C++ uses row-major](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#glossary) (C-like) memory layout so

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.]
 [ 3.  4.  5.]
 [ 6.  7.  8.]]
```

Is laying like `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` in memory. This means that if we have

```
x = np.zeros([time,batch,feature])
```

(`time_major=True` in tensorflow)

In Row-major memory we get a layout like `x[0,0,0],x[0,0,1],x[0,0,2],…,x[0,1,0],...` so ex. dot product of weights and vectors from the same sequence and timestep (`w*x[t,b,:]`) is the most contiguous operation followed by next sequence `w*x[t,b+1,:]` etc. This is what we want during training.

With `time_major=False` which is default we have [batch,time,feature] so ex features from same sequence but different timesteps are more contiguous i.e `w*x[batch,t,:]` followed by `w*x[batch,t+1,:]` etc. This might be faster for prediction of one sequence at a time if RNN is rolled out but this is speculation.

If you came to this question for the same reason I did, I learned to be careful with the slightly unintuitive Numpy-indexing which is meant to be pythonic, not necessarily Row Major. Look at this. As expected:

```
x = np.zeros([3,3])
x[0:9].flat = np.arange(10)
print x
>   [[ 0.  1.  2.]
>    [ 3.  4.  5.]
>    [ 6.  7.  8.]]
```

We would also expect `x[1] == x[0,1]` but

```
print x[1]
> [ 3.  4.  5.]

print x[np.arange(10)<=4]
> IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

Comment: + 1 for the efficiency breakdown. I came to this question from a curiosity as to whether a recurrent net will learn different dependency patterns with batch-major input.

Comment: I saw now that my answer was completely irrelevant, sorry for that. As to dependency patterns (I interpret as patterns), I can't see why this would be the case. If so I would designate it a bug

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference in what the model learns.

At timestep t, RNNs need results from t-1, therefore we need to compute things time-major. If `time_major=False`, TensorFlow transposes batch of sequences from `(batch_size, max_sequence_length)` to `(max_sequence_length, batch_size)`*. It processes the transposed batch one row at a time: at t=0, the first element of each sequence is processed, hidden states and outputs calculated; at t=max_sequence_length, the last element of each sequence is processed.

So if your data is already time-major, use `time_major=True`, which avoids a transpose. But there isn't much point in manually transposing your data before feeding it to TensorFlow.

*If you have multidimensional inputs (e.g. sequences of word embeddings: `(batch_size, max_sequence_length, embedding_size)`), axes 0 and 1 are transposed, leading to `(max_sequence_length, batch_size, embedding_size)`