# What's the difference between data time major and batch major?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Can anyone explain what data **time major** and **batch major** mean and what's the difference between them?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130491/batch-major-vs-time-major-lstm) answer your question?

Comment: Thank you , but no , didn't really get it from that post.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Trying to put it in simplest terms: these are different representations (or arrangements) of the *same* data.

### 2D example

For example, imagine you have the data like this (just for the sake of illustration, not real data):

```
1 11 21 31
2 12 22 32
3 13 23 33
...
100 111 121 131
```

... where each row corresponds to a training input and each column corresponds to a different feature. The matrix has size `(batch_size, features)`, where `batch_size=100` and `features=4`.

Next, in some cases, you may get a *transposed* matrix as input (for instance, it's an output from the previous step):

```
1 2 3 ... 100
11 12 13 ... 111
21 22 23 ... 121
31 32 33 ... 131
```

In this case, the matrix shape is `(features, batch_size)`. Note: the data itself doesn't change. Only the array dimensions have changed: batch is the 0-axis in the first example and 1-axis in the second example. Also note that one can swap different presentations very easily and efficiently. In tensorflow, it can be done with [`tf.transpose`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose).

### Time major vs Batch major

When in comes to RNNs, the tensors usually go to rank 3+, but the idea stays the same. If the input is `(batch_size, sequence_num, features)`, it's called **batch major**, because the 0 axis is the `batch_size`. If the input is `(sequence_num, batch_size, features)`, it's called **time major** likewise. The `features` is always the last dimension (at least I don't know real cases when it's not), so there's no further variety in naming.

Depending on the network structure, it might expect specifically the batch or the time as the 0 axis, so the format of input data matters. And depending on the previous layers, one can get either of the those representations to be fed into an RNN. So the conversion from one arrangement to another might be required, either by the library function or by the caller. As far as I can remember, batch major is the default in tensorflow and keras, so it simply boils down what shape is produced from the layer just before the RNN.

Once again: there is one-to-one correspondence between batch major and time major representations. Any tensor can be represented as both. But for a particular implementation, one of those can be expected or required.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks! Have I understood correctly, that 'sequence_num' refers to timesteps/sequence length?