# Tensorflow variable length timeseries training error with batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm trying to build a network with one input layer with 7 neurons, at least one LSTM layer, and an output layer of dimension 1. I've split my training data into smaller chunks so that I could train each topology candidate faster, but my validation data is only one sample (but a long time-series nonetheless). But it seems like I'm failing to communicate to Keras that the time_steps length is variable, while only the training data has a non-unitary batch size. Here's the code to reproduce the problem:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

rnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1, 7)))
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(5, activation="tanh", return_sequences=True, unroll=False,
                             recurrent_activation='sigmoid', use_bias=True, time_major=True,
                             recurrent_dropout=0, stateful=False, input_shape=(None, 7)))
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(5, activation="tanh", return_sequences=False, unroll=False,
                             recurrent_activation='sigmoid', use_bias=True, time_major=True,
                             recurrent_dropout=0, stateful=False, input_shape=(None, 5)))
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear"))
rnn.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")

batch_size = 6
x_train = np.random.rand(50, batch_size, 7)
y_train = np.random.rand(50, batch_size, 1)
x_val = np.random.rand(70, 1, 7)
y_val = np.random.rand(70, 1, 1)
rnn.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

x_test = np.random.rand(80, 1, 7)
y_test = np.random.rand(80, 1, 1)
rnn.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=1, batch_size=1)
```

At some point it gives this warning twice:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 1, 7) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 1, 7), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 6, 7).
```

Then later, an error message appears:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  required broadcastable shapes
     [[node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference (defined at D:\Rian\CloudRoot\Trabalhos\INPE\12 - Neurocomputação\CAP-351_Neurocomputing\4 - Recurrent Neural Network\reproduceProblemBatch.py:20) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4744]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

The Keras documentation says: (In LSTM page)

> time_major: The shape format of the inputs and outputs tensors. If True, the inputs and outputs will be in shape **[timesteps, batch, feature]**, whereas in the False case, it will be [batch, timesteps, feature]. Using time_major = True is a bit more efficient because it avoids transposes at the beginning and end of the RNN calculation. However, most TensorFlow data is batch-major, so by default this function accepts input and emits output in batch-major form.

So I'm not sure how to investigate further

Answer (score 1):

You have passed the input shape as `(1, 7)`, but when you check the shape of `x_train[0]`, it is `(6, 7)`. The data is `batch_major` and **not** `time_major`, hence kindly set `time_major=False` and also change the batch size of x_val and y_val. Please find the working code below

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

rnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()

# Change input shape to (6,7) 
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(6, 7)))

# Change time_major = False
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(5, activation="tanh", return_sequences=True, unroll=False,
                             recurrent_activation='sigmoid', use_bias=True, time_major=False,
                             recurrent_dropout=0, stateful=False, input_shape=(None, 7)))

# Change time_major = False
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(5, activation="tanh", return_sequences=False, unroll=False,
                             recurrent_activation='sigmoid', use_bias=True, time_major=False,
                             recurrent_dropout=0, stateful=False, input_shape=(None, 5)))
rnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="linear"))
rnn.compile(loss="mse", optimizer="adam")

batch_size = 6
x_train = np.random.rand(50, batch_size, 7)
y_train = np.random.rand(50, batch_size, 1)
x_val = np.random.rand(70, batch_size, 7) # Change 1 to batch_size
y_val = np.random.rand(70, batch_size, 1) # Change 1 to batch_size
rnn.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

x_test = np.random.rand(80, 1, 7)
y_test = np.random.rand(80, 1, 1)
rnn.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=1, batch_size=1)
```

**Output:**

```
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 98ms/step - loss: 0.5661 - val_loss: 0.4955
80/80 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.3359
0.3358885943889618
```

For more information on batch_major and time_major, please refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48785721/14290697). Thank you!